# Swift 4 how to print text to label

Tags: swift, text

I am trying to print text into a text field like this:
How to do that the right way?

```
else {

        weak var worgnlogin: UILabel! {
            worgnlogin.text = ("brugernavn eller password er skrevet forkert")

          }
    }
```

Here you have my main ViewController code I have made an array with all users infomation,  as I will loop through and get the right user to login:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var worgLogin: UILabel!

let user1 = ["user": "Karsten","userID":"1","userName":"Kalle","passWord":"1234" ]
let user2 = ["user": "Rene","userID":"2","userName":"Rene" ,"passWord":"1234" ]
let user3 = ["user": "Johan","userID":"3","userName":"Johan","passWord":"1234" ]




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let array = [user1,user2,user3]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "users")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN") == true {
        //user is already logged in just navigate him to home screen
        let homeVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVc, animated: false)
    }
}


@IBAction func authenticateUser(_ sender: Any) {
    if txtUserName.text == "userName" && txtPassword.text == "passWord" {
        //navigate to home screen
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN")
        let homeVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVc, animated: true)
    }else {
        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Brugernavn eller Password er skrevet forkert");

        return;
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:nil);

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);

    self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);

}
```

}
i hobe this make a better understanding :)

Comment: Only this in else `worgnlogin.text = "brugernavn eller password er skrevet forkert"`
`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First create an IBOutlet for a label:

```
@IBOutlet weak var worgnLoginLabel: UILabel!
```

Then in your else statement write:

```
self.worgnLoginLabel.text = “your message”
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/71930/angela       i do not know what to do i will like to close tis task/ questions  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
worgnlogin.text = "brugernavn eller password er skrevet forkert"
```

Comment: So i have to make a label on my main storryBoard first ?

Comment: Yes please.  Create a label on storyboard . Drag and create its outlet in View Controller class. After that assign text to your label.

Comment: Now when i thy to buid the this happens:

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?    Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: “Thread 1: signal SIGABRT”  means there is something missing and not able to acces. Check if your outlets are properly connected.

Comment: declaration line should be in class scope not inside else , then assign the value as in answer in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Okay Now it works  but how hide label when there is text?

Comment: okay it's everything works fine now so how do close this ticket ?

Comment: Accept my answer to close it.